# How to query old (one time) purchased items with play billing libray v6.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am migrating from In-App Billing v3 to Play Billing Library v6.0.1. I am stucked at a point where I need to query and confirm old (one time) purchases with play billing library v6.0.1. With in-app billing v3 it was easy to query a purchase by using this method

> .isPurchased()

and it would return if an item is purchased or not. In this new play billing library v6.0.1 there exits no such convenient method to perform this task easily.

**Provide a code sample where I am able to query and confirm old purchases with play billing library v6.0.1.**

Answer (score 0):

You can query if user has already purchased any of your subscription or one-time products using this snippet :

```
public static void isAlreadyPurchaseQuery() {
    if (billingClient.isReady()) {

        billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP).build(), new PurchasesResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {
                if (!list.isEmpty()){
                    if (list.get(0).getProducts().contains("your one-time purchase key")){
                        // purchased = true
                    } else {
                        billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS).build(), new PurchasesResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {
                                if (!list.isEmpty()){
                                    if (list.get(0).getProducts().contains("Your subscription key")){
                                        // purchased = true
                                    } else {
                                        // purchased = false
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // purchased = false
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS).build(), new PurchasesResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {
                            if (!list.isEmpty()){
                                if (list.get(0).getProducts().contains("Your subscription key")){
                                    // purchased = true
                                } else {
                                    // purchased = false
                                }
                            } else {
                                // purchased = false
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Use this method after initialising billing client.
You can also refer to official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#fetch).